# Как управлять разработкой проекта?

Tags: архитектура

Мы сейчас делаем десктопное приложение на C#.

Мы - это:

- Два молодых программиста (я и мой коллега). Мы пишем код.
- Опытный программист. Он следит, чтобы мы работали и задает направление нашей работы, ставит задачи. При этом не вникает в код и не знает его структуру.
- Человек, который общается с заказчиком.

Стратегия написания кода такая:

- пишем хоть как абы работало
- когда код становится очень длинным и хаотичным, рефакторим его.

С коллегой я долгое время не могла договориться о порядке работы. Я не понимала, что именно он делает, что хочет сделать, и почему именно так. Часто бывало так, что работа плохо делилась на двоих и тогда мы теряли время. Сейчас он взял отпуск. Я наконец разобралась в проекте и стала понимать, что происходит.
Сейчас я хочу структурировать проект и как-то это записать. Может, нарисовать на бумаге. Чтобы увидеть всю систему в целом. Какие модули есть, какие классы в каждом модуле, за что они отвечают.

Думаю, это помогло бы

- каждому из нас понимать, что именно делает другой
- вспомнить проект через год, или быстро объяснить его новому разработчику
- да и просто знать, что работает и как (например, в одном из наших прошлых проектов было несколько похожих классов, обозначающих интервал времени. это нехорошо)
- не забывать актуальные проблемы и недоработки каждого модуля
- сначала продумать структуру, а потом уже писать код (было бы меньше хаоса и рефакторинга)

Еще хочется документировать в явном виде правила и допущения (напр. "входные данные о времени только в local time")

Так вот, как правильно называется то, что я хочу сделать? И как лучше это сделать? Есть ли какие-то общепринятые инструменты?
Как поддерживать целостность (чтобы записанный план проекта соответствовал коду)?
Есть ли про это хорошие книги (английский знаю)?
Может, я вообще ерундой занимаюсь, и стоит просто писать код как у нас принято, путаться в нем и надеяться, что как-то прокатит?

Единственный ответ, который удалось нагуглить, был вроде: "это приходит с опытом. Станешь сеньором - узнаешь. А пока пиши код, студент."

Comment: Описывать проект человеческим языком (начиная с ТЗ) и составлять планы (а также еженедельные отчеты по их выполнению)   крайне полезно. Основной инструмент -- любимый текстовый редактор.

Answer (score 1):

> Какие модули есть, какие классы в каждом модуле, за что они отвечают.

Ну, допустим Вы составите такую подробную спецификацию... Что дальше? Что Вам это даст? Как и, главное, кто будет поддерживать её в актуальном состоянии?

Из личного опыта. Если попали на проект с таким качеством кода, нужно или рефакторить, приводя в нормальный вид, (если есть время) или писать комментарии, чтобы открыв класс можно было прочитать о чём он.

Однако даже если есть время для рефакторинга, при его проведении программисту необходимо соблюдать всем известную заповедь врача: "Не навреди!".

А, чтобы не навредить очень желательно набраться знаний и опыта.

Разумеется, что помимо самой разработки, рабочий процесс в общем должен быть организован соответствующим образом, но это уже больше в компетенции руководства, начиная с тимлида.

> Есть ли про это хорошие книги (английский знаю)?

Они есть даже в переводе на русский. Откройте для себя С. Макконелла ("Совершенный код) и книги Р.Мартина, М.Фаулера и т.д.

Comment: Не соглашусь в первым тезисом. Рисовать надо, что хотя бы для себя разложить по полочкам текущее состояние. И да, чем на более общем уровне рисуете, тем дольше этот рисунок будет отражать общую структуру проекта.